# Associative Array in LaTeX (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, arrays, loops

I'm modifying a calendar by *Robert Krause* ([TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/a-calender-for-doublesided-din-a4/)) and I'm searching for a method to get this calendar work dynamically. See also my original post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346023/calendar-which-displays-all-events).

As nobody has answered on that oruginal post, I'm asking this new question, which is probably helpful for many other users and diverese uses. How can I define an associative array in `Tikz` and loop through it?

In my case this array should look like this:

```
\exams = [
    {Chemistry}{2017-05-13},
    {Maths}{2017-06-26},
    {Physics}{2017-03-11}
]
```

In my calendar code, where the cells are defined, I have to loop through this array to check, if there are any exams to display:

```
% Tikzpicture environment for the first six month of the year
\foreach{\exams as \exam => \date}{
    \if{\date <= \year-06-30}{
        \exam{\date}{\exam}
    }
}

% Tikzpicture environment for the last six month of the year
\foreach{\exams as \exam => \date}{
    \if{\date > \year-06-30}{
        \exam{\date}{\exam}
    }
}
```

This little makro is used to write the name into the field:

```
\def\exam#1#2{
    \node [
        anchor=north west, 
        text width= 3.4cm,
        text=red,
        font=\bf
    ] at
    ($(cal-#1.north west)+(3em, -0.2em)$) {\scriptsize{#2}};
}
```

It is called like this:

```
\exam{2017-06-23}{Physical Chemistry}
```

The loop should call this makro and insert the date and name.

Comment: it is rather hard to debug disconnected fragments, if #1 is `2017-06-23` what is the intention of  `cal-2017-06-23.north west` where is that node defined?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please check the code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e294e62dc15a9dd6d42d3ffa9c9870dd). I would really enjoy your help :)

Answer (score 4):

The tikz syntax is rather different (and tex doesn't really have arrays) but you can iterate through subject/date pairs, which seems to be the main requirement here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\year{2017}
\errorcontextlines1000
\begin{document}

\def\exams {
    Chemistry/2017-05-13,
    Maths/2017-06-26,
    Physics/2017-03-11,
    French/2017-08-01
}
\def\datenum#1{\expandafter\xdatenum#1\relax}
\def\xdatenum#1-#2-#3\relax{#1#2#3}

A:

% Tikzpicture environment for the first six month of the year
\foreach \subject/\sdate in \exams{
\ifnum\datenum\sdate<\datenum{\year-06-30}
 [exam \sdate, \subject]\par
\fi
}

B:

% Tikzpicture environment for the last six month of the year
\foreach \subject/\sdate in \exams{
\ifnum\datenum\sdate > \datenum{\year-06-30}
   [exam \sdate, \subject]\par
\fi
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if the exam subject has several words? -> Physical Chemistry

Comment: @Sam `{Physical Chemistry}/2017-09-01`

Comment: Cool, thank you! Would you be so kind and look at the edits in the question? I'm currently unable to get it working :/