# Set a fixed height for calendar rows

Tags: tables, calendar

I want to create a calendar with LaTeX but ended up with some rows which are higher (marked red) than all the other rows. I understand why these rows are higher (cell content). But is there a way to restrict the row hight? I am happy to have the cell content trimmed. I am happy to go a totally different way in case this approach doesn't make sense and there is a better one.

At the end I need to populate the single cells automatically with very limited chance to analyse the text (no human ever lays hand on this during production). I need a LaTeX solution which takes care of it (e.g. trimming the text).

Is there a solution for this problem?

The source code:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/gvqqkwrzddjq

[image]

Comment: Would you consider using [tag:tikz-calendar] for your calendar? It doesn't immediately solve your  problem but it is much easier to work with – once it is set up. [Example.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663804/16595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to typeset the `\textnote`s in a `\parbox` with a fixed height. E.g.

```
 \newcommand{\textnote}[1]{
    \parbox[c][8mm]{1.5cm}{\raggedleft\scriptsize\hfill#1}
 }
```

You may have to experiment with the sizes.